# create mongoose schema for this object from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like to create a schema following this model schema.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "617dda9ec688cc58f8db259e",
        "location": "The Hunt Club",
        "numbers": 12,
        "available": [true, false]
    }
]
```

So far I have the below code, but does not seems to be working:

```
const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    location: {
        type: "string",
        required: true
    },
    numbers:{
        type: "number",
        required: true
    },
    available:{
        type:[Boolean],
        required: true
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now,
    }
})

const locations = mongoose.model('location', locationSchema);
module.exports = locations;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html
For defining the type of the element, the type will be interpreted. You could use the native type `String` instead of `"string"` or `Number`.

```
numbers:{
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
```